# unable to modify global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

```js
var address ="<%= params[:search] %>";
var lat;
var long;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
 lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
 long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
}); 
alert(lat);
//wanna use lat and long here!
```

browser always alert "undefined" when called outside the function, works when called from within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geocoder.geocode` function is asynchronous, and it receives latitude and longitude inside a callback function - after the asynchronous operation is complete. Only then the `lat` and `long` variables are defined.

Your alert runs immediately after **starting** the asynchronous operation, meaning that it's still not complete by the time the alert is fired. So, `lat` and `long` are still undefined.

You cannot use latitude and longitude outside of the callback block. Move it inside the callback block and it will work:

```
var address ="<%= params[:search] %>";
var lat;
var long;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    // you can use lat and lng inside here! :)
    alert(lat);
});
```

Read this post if you want to get a better understanding of asynchronous code in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/2401947

Comment: thanks a lot! I moved the whole code inside those parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Ashutosh Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9905915/ashutosh-gupta),

this happens because your `alert()` happens before variable assignment.
You can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to solve this issue, like

```
var address ="<%= params[:search] %>";
var lat;
var lng;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    resolve({lat: lat, lng: lng});
}));
}).then((data) => {
    alert(data);
});
```